Run local Azure Function with NService Bus Service Bus Trigger
I am trying to test and run an Azure function locally using NService bus and a Service Bus Trigger.
Using Azure Functions Core Tools you can invoke a non-http trigger function using the administrator endpoint.
I am able to "hit" the endpoint but NService bus is throwing an exception because the NService bus messages include several "message headers" - one of which is thte NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes header that specifies the message contract.
Using postman - I am posting the payload required by the administrator endpoint:

{
    "input": "/{my escaped event object}/"
}

I tried setting the http headers on the postman post:

    Request Headers
    Content-Type: application/json
    NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes: Namespace.Models.MyEvent
    User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.42.0
    Accept: */*

I get an exception:

    System.Exception: The System.Text.Json message serializer requires message types to be defined.

I am using the System.Text.Json serializer - the type cannot be inferred and needs to be included in the message. 

The question is how do I test a full Nservice bus message through the Http Admin tool with Azure Core tools?



That won't work. It's not an HTTP-triggered function to provide ASB headers with HTTP headers. If the admin function mechanism doesn't support ASB-specific use cases, you're better off sending a message to the queue using ASB REST API and triggering your local function that way. Notice how the non-HTTP section shows an example with Storage Queues? That's because that service doesn't support headers, and everything sent in the HTTP body is turned into the message's payload. You could ask this question in the Functions tooling repo, linking here with an answer.

Raised it here.

Service bus messages do not have any headers. It only takes everything has message body.

And that's the problem. You need to be able to pass a header.
